# Wrapping post content with multiple columns around a featured image that spans multiple colums

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a client that is asking for their blog posts to look like this:

[image]

I'm able to get the text to wrap around the image pretty easily, but the issue is the multiple columns... they do not wrap as normal text would.

I've tried the following:

Here's a jsfiddle with the text wrapping
https://jsfiddle.net/bynxaudio/jktx9mrc/

```
#featured-image{
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/oOjQ7bD.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 63%;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#post-content{
  text-align: justify;
}
```

and here's an example of the same code, but the text has 3 columns
https://jsfiddle.net/bynxaudio/L53wpjyx/3/

```
#featured-image{
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/oOjQ7bD.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 63%;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#post-content{
  text-align: justify;
  column-count: 3;
}
```

The only other solution I can think of would be to create two divs to contain content and to split text into an array and then place each array element in each of its' respective divs, like #post-content-1 and #post-content-2 in this example.

Thanks for all your help.  I seriously appreciate it.

Comment: You should post the code you've tried.

Comment: Quite simply, text doesn't flow usually like that in a web page (you have a *print* layout). You *could* fake it with CSS-Grid (may be CSS-Shape Outside) and, perhaps with CSS-columns but i suspect the effort would be not worth the hassle.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've updated it with a couple of jsfiddles

Comment: @Paulie_D That's what I was thinking as well.  Thanks for your input!